# How to Bind sharepoint LIST to a Sql DB table

Tags: sharepoint, data-binding, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Is there a way to Bind share point list to Sql Db tables to fetch the updates dynamically. Example: I have a share point list of 2 columns and, I have azure sql Db table with 2 columns. I would like to bind them together so when an update is happened in DB column, respective share point list column data will be updated.

I have tried write a sprint book job to do this but, it is lot of code to maintain. Also we need to manage the real time sync on our own.

I am expecting there might be some out of the box connecter in Microsoft flow, or azure logic app or something automation which will help me automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you check BCS so your db data could sync with SharePoint external list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-external-list

Another thread with demo.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrate-azure-sql-db-with-sharepoint-online-as-an-external-list-using-business/

Answer (score 0):

There is SQL Server connector, suppose this is what you want. You could use the trigger `When an item is created` or `When an item is modified` to get the sql updates details.

The output would be like the below pic shows.

[image]

Further more information you could refer to this doc:[SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/).**Note:** there are some known limitation, like When invoking triggers,

> A ROWVERSION column is required for OnUpdatedItems
>
> An IDENTITY column is required for OnNewItems

After the trigger, you could use the table details to [update sharepoint list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#update-item).

Hope this could help you.